# How to force refresh on react instant search dom in algolia or fetch updated data as soon as it finished?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am integrating algolia with react-instant-search-dom in firebase.
After i update a product, I want the updated result to be reflected on the front end but it is not working as expected. It sometimes works but sometimes not.
I have used every possible way like using refresh param and clearCache method but none of them worked 100%.
Could anyone of here can help me?
This is my code snippet.

```
const handleEdit = (productData) => {
      updateProduct()
          .then((data) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setRefresh(true);
              setTimeout(() => {
                setRefresh(false);
              }, 100);
            }, 7000);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error when saving new product data:", err.message);
          });
      })
  };
<InstantSearch
        indexName={AlgoliaSearchConfig.appIndexName}
        searchClient={searchClient}
        refresh={refresh}
  >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinitializing algoliasearch object or the `searchClient` seem to do the trick.

Here is a sandbox to see it in action : https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-easley-2l0zi2?file=/src/App.js

Now its not recommended (or best practise) to reinitialize an object on every key stroke while searching. What you can see in the sandbox is that, whenever we make an update or save data, we initialize a new algoliasearch object. Otherwise we don't on every keystroke (search).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not 100%. @Mujeeb Qureshi

Comment: not 100% as in? Can you elaborate where the conditions where it seems to fail even on new initialization?

Comment: Yeah, i used the same way as you used. After updating, i re-initialized the algoliaClient but it also doesnt work 100% perfect. It worked but sometimes not.

Comment: the point is, I just gave a proof of concept. But If your implementation has an InstantSearch component then its best to keep searchClient in state like `const [searchClient, setsearchClient] = useState(algoliasearch(id,key))`

Comment: Yeah, i also used that method. 
My code looks like
 `const [searchClient, setSearchClient] = useState(
    algoliasearch(AlgoliaSearchConfig.appId, AlgoliaSearchConfig.apiKey)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refresh) {
      setSearchClient(
        algoliasearch(AlgoliaSearchConfig.appId, AlgoliaSearchConfig.apiKey)
      );
    }
  }, [refresh]);

<InstantSearch
        indexName={AlgoliaSearchConfig.appIndexName}
        searchClient={searchClient}
      >`
Here `refresh` variable is updated when db changes. but it is not working.

Comment: When you say "not 100% perfect" do you never see the new result or is it eventually consistent? Depending on how quickly you expect to see the new result, you may be coming up against indexing delays on the service side.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `refresh` prop on InstantSearch:

```js
const App = () => {
  let [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false)

  let onSearchStateChange = (state) => {
    setRefresh(false)
  }

  return (
    <InstantSearch
      onSearchStateChange={onSearchStateChange}
      refresh={refresh}
    >
    </InstantSearch>
  )
};
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/pull/619